# how to redirect to a screen when app is opened from push notification in react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-navigation, aws-amplify

I am working on a react native app with aws-amplify library https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/push-notifications .When I click on push notification, my app should redirect to notification screen.I am not getting the navigation props when i open the app from notification , So I am using this to work without prop https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html but still I am getting this error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.dispatch')".I am using react-navigation in my app

```
 import PushNotification from '@aws-amplify/pushnotification';
 import NotificationList from './NotificationList';
 import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

   Analytics.configure(awsmobile);

  PushNotification.configure(awsmobile);


if(Platform.OS === 'android'){


PushNotification.onNotification((notification) => {

    // console.log('in app notification : Outside App', notification);

    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
      bypassCache: false  // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
    }).then(user => {

    console.log('Current user : Outside App', user.attributes.sub)

    const currentDate = new Date();

    const todayDate = moment(currentDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

    var todayTime = moment().format('HH:mm:ss')

    const notificationDetails = {
        userId: user.attributes.sub,
        userTitle: notification.title,
        userBody: notification.body,
        userDate: todayDate,
        userTime: todayTime,
    };

    console.log("notificationDetails outside", notificationDetails)

    API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUserNotification, { input: notificationDetails }))
        .then(response => {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error Saving Details...', err);
            this.setState({ showActivityIndicator: false });
    });

  });

});

  PushNotification.onNotificationOpened((notification) => {

        const b = new Home();

        console.log('onNotificationOpened 1');

        b._handleNotificationOpen(notification)


  });

}

 class Home extends React.Component {


 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

  global.ShowRecordVar = "12"

  this._handleNotificationOpen =  
  this._handleNotificationOpen.bind(this);



  this.state = {
    apiResponse: 0,
    loading: true,

  }
 }

_handleNotificationOpen = (notification) => {

 if (notification["pinpoint.deeplink"]) {

    NavigationService.navigate('NotificationList',{notification});

 }
}

//Some More Codes

}
```

Comment: This implies that your NavigationService doesn't have a reference to the `navigatorRef`. Are you sure you've setup the ref correctly as in the example? 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: Yes I have setup the ref correctly,the error occured when the app is in killed state i.e not in the background.When the app is in the background it navigates properly.